# Sum a column of SparseVectors in PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a column of SparseVectors like this:

```
+--------------------+
|      features_array|
+--------------------+
|(11,[1,2,3],[1.0,...|
|(11,[1,2],[1.0,1.0])|
|(11,[1,2],[1.0,1.0])|
|(11,[1,4],[1.0,1.0])|
|(11,[1,3,4],[1.0,...|
+--------------------+
```

And just want to sum all the rows without converting to an RDD first. I should end up with just one sparse vector. I've tried a bunch of things but keep getting a bunch of schema mismatch errors.

If I had dense vectors, the input and output would be like this:

Input:

```
feature_array
[1,2]
[3,5]
```

Output:

```
feature_array
[4,7]
```

Comment: for spark 2.4+, check `df.select(Summarizer.normL1(df.features_array)).show()`, link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.stat.Summarizer.normL1

Comment: @jxc Thank you! Is this something I can use with the Window function?

Comment: you can define `summarizer = Summarizer.metrics("normL1")` and then use something like `df.select(summarizer.summary(df.features_array).over(w1).alias('summary'))`. where w1 is your WindowSpec.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. One more question: Is there a way to do this and add the output as a column to an existing dataframe? WithColumn doesn't seem to work.

Comment: withColumn works from my testing. you can also just add '*' to df.select(): `df.select('*', summarizer.summary(df.features_array).over(w1).alias('summary'))`

Comment: BTW. normL1 is the sum of the absolute values. it will not work if there are negative values in the vectors.

Comment: @jxc This works! Thanks! I was wondering if you're familiar with the rdd interface? According to documentation, the DF interface is 2x-3x slower than the rdd one.

Comment: whenever possible, stick with the DF-based APIs, not just because they are much faster than RDD-based. if you are working on Spark ML projects, the RDD-based pyspark.mllib has been in maintenance mode since spark 2.0. check https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/ml-guide.html